# Sending calls to libraries remotely across linux

Tags: c, linux, openssl

I am developing some experimental setup in C.

I am exploring a scenario as follows and I need help to understand it.

I have a system A which has a lot of Applications using cryptographic algorithms.

But these crypto calls(openssl calls) should be sent to another System B which takes care of cryptography.

Therefore, I have to send any calls to cryptographic (openssl) engines via socket to a remote system(B) which has openssl support.

My plan is to have a small socket prog on System A which forwards these calls to system B.

What I'm still unclear at this moment is how I handle the received commands at System B.

Do I actually get these commands and translate them into corresponding calls to openssl locally in my system? This means I have to program whatever is done on System A right?

Or is there a way to tunnel/send these raw lines of code to the openssl libs directly and just received the result and then resend to System A

How do you think I should go about the problem?

PS: Oh by the way, the calls to cryptography(like EngineUpdate, VerifyFinal etc or Digest on System A can be either on Java or C.. I already wrote a Java/C program to send these commands to System B via sockets...
The problem is only on System B and how I have to handle..

Answer (score 1):

You could use sockets on B, but that means you need to define a protocol for that. Or you use RPC (remote procedure calls).

Examples for socket programming can be found [here](http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/practical/CSockets/textcode.html).

RPC is explained [here](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node33.html#SECTION003300000000000000000).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (not to say "the easy", but still) way I can imagine would be to:

1. Write wrapper (proxy) versions of the libraries you want to make remote.
2. Write a server program that listens to calls, performs them using the real local libraries, and sends the result back.
3. Preload the proxy library before running any application where you want to do this.

Of course, there are many many problems with this approach:

1. It's not exactly trivial to define a serializing protocol for generic C function calls.
2. It's not exactly trivial to write the server, either.
3. Applications will slow a lot, since the proxy call needs to be synchronous.
4. What about security of the data on the network?

**UPDATE**:

As requested in a comment, I'll try to expand a bit. By "wrapper" I mean a new library, that has the same API as another one, but does not in fact contain the same code. Instead, the wrapper library will contain code to serialize the arguments, call the server, wait for a response, de-serialize the result(s), and present them to the calling program as if nothing happened.

Since this involves a lot of tedious, repetitive and error-prone code, it's probably best to abstract it by making it code-driven. The best would be to use the original library's header file to define the serialization needed, but that (of course) requires quite heavy C parsing. Failing that, you might start bottom-up and make a custom language to describe the calls, and then use that to generate the serialization, de-serialization, and proxy code.

On Linux systems, you can control the dynamic linker so that it loads your proxy library instead of the "real" library. You could of course also replace (on disk) the real library with the proxy, but that will break all applications that use it if the server is not working, which seems very risky.

Comment: What is exactly a wrapper? Do I have to redo the calls here? Can you elaborate a bit. And yes, I already started writing a server program which implements one such call to the library on the remote system. It waits for all parameters from System A and then calls the libs locally as you said and then return the result. But I am afraid it will grow tedious if I start doing this for each and every function call... Hence my questions. By the way where is the wrapper that you suggested? Do please explain.

Answer (score 0):

So you basically have two choices, each outlined by unwind and ammoQ respectively:

(1) Write a server and do the socket/protocol work etc., yourself.  You can minimize some of the pain by using solutions like [Google's protocol buffers.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers)

(2) use an existing middleware solution like (a) message queues or (b) an RPC mechanism like CORBA and its many alternatives

Either is probably more work than you anticipated.  So really you have to answer this yourself.  How serious is your project?  How varied is your hardware?  How likely is the hardware and software configuration to change in the future?

If this is more than a learning or pet project you are going to be bored with in a month or two then an existing middleware solution is probably the way to go.  The downside is there is a somewhat intimidating learning curve.

You can go the RPC route with [CORBA](http://www.omg.org/gettingstarted/corbafaq.htm), [ICE](http://www.zeroc.com/ice.html), or whatever the Java solutions are these days (RMI? EJB?), and a bunch of others.  This is an elegant solution since your calls to the remote encryption machine appear to your SystemA as simple function calls and the middleware handles the data issues and sockets.  But you aren't going to learn them in a weekend.

Personally I would look to see if a message queue solution like [AMQP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Message_Queuing_Protocol) would work for you first.  There is less of a learning curve than RPC.

Comment: Thanks all.This is a research proj. The OSes are embedded linux at  B and Android at A. System B is completely C coded. Hence socket commn to talk to B is Java code while the handling of the calls is done by C socket server. Got to work on the "wrapper" part at C socket server side. If RPC is a better way, I'd like to check out. Now I have to connect C server to openssl libs via the wrapper and reply to the Java client waiting on SystemA.

Note that our project revolves around an embedded system B and A is not of interest to us(other than the small piece of Java client that talks to B!).